# The integral in the Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $I$ be a non-empty open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and consider the Sobolev space $$H^{1}(I):=\left\{ u \in L^{2}(I) : Du \in L^{2}(I)\right\}$$ with norm $\|u\|^{2}_{H^{1}(I)}:=\|u\|^{2}_{L^{2}(I)}+\|Du\|_{L^{2}(I)}^{2}$.

An interesting subspace is the closure of $C^{\infty}_c(I)$ in $H^{1}(I)$ where $C^{\infty}_c(I)$ is the collection of infinitely differentiable functions compactly supported in $I$. Such closure is denoted by $H^{1}_{0}(I)$.

I would like to show that $\int_{I}f(x)g'(x) dx= - \int_{I}f'(x)g(x)dx$ for every $f \in H^{1}(I)$ and $g \in H^{1}_{0}(I)$.

From the definition of $H^{1}(I)$, $f \in H^{1}(I)$ implies that there exists $f' \in L^2(I)$ such that $\int_{I}f(x)g'(x) dx= - \int_{I}f'(x)g(x)dx$ for every $g \in C^{\infty}_c(I)$, but I am not sure how such equality holds when $g \in H^{1}_{0}(I)$.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You prove this by density, look:

First take $g \in C_{0}^{\infty}(I)$, then $\int_{I}{f(x)g'(x)}dx =  \langle f, g'\rangle_{\mathcal{D}', \mathcal{D}} = - \langle f', g \rangle_{\mathcal{D}', \mathcal{D}} = - \int_{I}{f'(x)g(x)}dx$. This is the definition of distributional derivatives. For a general function $g \in H_{0}^{1}(I)$, there exists a sequence $(g_{n})$ such that, $g_{n} \in C_{c}^{\infty}$ and $g_{n} \to g$ in $H^{1}$, thus $g_{n} \to g$ and $g_{n}' \to g'$ in $L^{2}$ which implies that,
$$\int_{I}{f(x)g_{n}'(x)}dx - \int_{I}{f(x)g'(x)}dx \to 0$$ 
and 
$$\int_{I}{f'(x)g_{n}(x)}dx - \int_{I}{f'(x)g(x)}dx \to 0$$
therefore, as $\int_{I}{f(x)g_{n}'(x)}dx = -\int_{I}{f'(x)g_{n}(x)}dx$ (for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$) you have your result (uniqueness of the limit).

Comment: You can write '\langle' and '\rangle' in math mode to get $\langle$ and $\rangle$ (they look better for the inner product).

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind and insightful answer.